# Perl Encoding - Saving File to UTF8

Tags: html, perl, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a script that will download www pages, and I want to extract the text and store it in a uniform encoding (UTF8 would be fine).  The downloading (UserAgent), Parsing  (TreeBuilder) and text extraction seem fine, but  I'm not sure I'm saving them correctly.

They dont view when opening the output file in for example notepad++;  The original HTML views find in a text editor.

The HTML files typically have 
    charset=windows-1256 or 
    charset=UTF-8

So I figured if I could get the UTF8 one to work, then it was just an recoding problem.  Here is some of what I have tried, assuming I have an HTML file saved to disk.

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$tree->parse_file("$inhtml");
$tree->dump;
```

The output from dump  captured for STDOUT views correctly in .txt file only after
Switching the encoding to utf8 in the text editor…

```
$formatter = HTML::FormatText->new(leftmargin => 0, rightmargin => 50);
if (utf8::is_utf8($formatter->format($tree))) {
    print "   Is UTF8\n";
}
else {
    print "   Not UTF8\n";
}
```

Result Shows  this IS UTF8 when the content says it is, and Not UTF8 otherwise.

I have tired

```
opening an file with ">" and ">:utf8"
binmode(MYFILE, ":utf8");
encode("utf8", $string); (where string is the output of formatter->format(tree))
```

But nothing seems to work correctly.

Any experts out there know what Im missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example can help you to find what you need:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use HTML::TreeBuilder qw( );
use Object::Destroyer qw( );

open(my $fh_in,  "<:encoding(cp1252)", $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
open(my $fh_out, ">:encoding(UTF-8)",  $ARGV[1]) or die $!;

my $tree = Object::Destroyer->new(HTML::TreeBuilder->new(), 'delete');
$tree->parse_file($fh_in);

my $h1Element = $tree->look_down("_tag", "h1");
my $h1TrimmedText = $h1Element->as_trimmed_text();
say($fh_out $h1TrimmedText);
```

Comment: Looks like The problem is the input encoding.  I assumed since perl was reading in something, if it was UTF-8, it would have read it correctly.  Apparently not!   This code helped.... Now I just have to figure out which encoding for each file type!  When there is a content_type tag, its trivial, but otherwise...?  Any way to do that automatically?

Comment: @TerpFan - My code allows you to select correct input encoding, so it should work for you if you know encoding of that input. If not encoding type is provided, then it should be your default reading encoding. I hope my answer helped you. If so, please accept my answer (click on check-mark below number left next to my answer - it will change color to green). Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Thank you.  Since Im working with HTML files, I was able to open first and find the encoding, then reopen it correctly!  that was the key..... I assumed perl opened the file correctly in the first palce... if ($fileline =~ m/charset=(\S+)\"/ ) {
  $charset = $1;

Comment: @TerpFan: as you download files with HTTP, you should first look at the `charset` in the `Content-Type` header, before looking in the `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score -3):

I really like the module [`utf8::all`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8%3a%3aall) (unfortunately not in core).

Just `use utf8::all` and you have no worries about IO, when you work only with UTF-8 files.